# Update database from database on other server

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, updating

Is there possibility to getting/updating  (for eg. one update per hour) fields from databse on server 1 and put them into server 2?

Any ideas?

Comment: You should use the "replication" feature of MySQL for this.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use a serer script on server 1 and call it from server 2 with an hourly cron job.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?PHP
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$today = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//remember to change the password to whatever you set
//it to in mysql instance configuration

//first parameter is server name, 2nd username 'root', 3rd is password

$rst = @mysql_connect("localhost","user1","password1","dbname1");
$rst1 = @mysql_connect("localhost","user2","password2","dbname2");


if (!$rst){
     echo( "<p>Unable to connect to database manager.</p>");
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     exit();
} else {
  //echo("<p>Successfully Connected to MySQL Database Manager!</p>");
}

if (! @mysql_select_db("dbname1") ){
     echo( "<p>Unable to  connect database...</p>");
     exit();
} else {
  //echo("<p>Successfully Connected to Database 'MYSQL'!</p>");
}


if (!$rst1){
     echo( "<p>Unable to connect to database manager.</p>");
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     exit();
} else {
 // echo("<p>Successfully Connected to MySQL Database Manager!</p>");
}

if (! @mysql_select_db("dbname2") ){
     echo( "<p>Unable to  connect database...</p>");
     exit();
} else {
 // echo("<p>Successfully Connected to Database 'MYSQL'!</p>");
}
?>

<?php   
$count=0; 
$rst1 = @mysql_connect("localhost","user2","password2","dbname2");
if (!$rst1){
     echo( "<p>Unable to connect to database manager.</p>");
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     exit();
} else {
 // echo("<p>Successfully Connected to MySQL Database Manager!</p>");
}

if (! @mysql_select_db("dbname2") ){
     echo( "<p>Unable to  connect database...</p>");
     exit();
} else {
 // echo("<p>Successfully Connected to Database 'MYSQL'!</p>");
}

$SQLDEL = mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE dbname2.table2");

$rst = @mysql_connect("localhost","user1","password1","dbname1");
if (!$rst){
     echo( "<p>Unable to connect to database manager.</p>");
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     exit();
} else {
  //echo("<p>Successfully Connected to MySQL Database Manager!</p>");
}

if (! @mysql_select_db("dbname1") ){
     echo( "<p>Unable to  connect database...</p>");
     exit();
} else {
  //echo("<p>Successfully Connected to Database 'MYSQL'!</p>");
}
$crfselect=mysql_query("select * from dbname1.tablename");
$crfselectsql=mysql_fetch_array($crfselect);
$rst1 = @mysql_connect("localhost","user2","password2","dbname2");
if (!$rst1){
     echo( "<p>Unable to connect to database manager.</p>");
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     exit();
} else {
 // echo("<p>Successfully Connected to MySQL Database Manager!</p>");
}

if (! @mysql_select_db("dbname2") ){
     echo( "<p>Unable to  connect database...</p>");
     exit();
} else {
 // echo("<p>Successfully Connected to Database 'MYSQL'!</p>");
}
while($crfselectsql)
{
$inserttrustfind=mysql_query("insert into dbname2.tablename set //Your fields");
$count++;
$crfselectsql=mysql_fetch_array($crfselect);    
}
if($inserttrustfind)
{
    $rst = @mysql_connect("localhost","user1","password1","dbname1");
if (!$rst){
     echo( "<p>Unable to connect to database manager.</p>");
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
     exit();
} else {
  //echo("<p>Successfully Connected to MySQL Database Manager!</p>");
}

if (! @mysql_select_db("dbanme1") ){
     echo( "<p>Unable to  connect database...</p>");
     exit();
} else {
  //echo("<p>Successfully Connected to Database 'MYSQL'!</p>");
}

// TO KEEP COPY DATE IN DATABASE
$insetsqyn = mysql_query("insert into dbname1.databasesynch set synctime='$today'");
}
if($insetsqyn)
    {
    echo "<script>location.href='checker_punching.php'</script>";
    exit();
    }
    else
    {
    }

?>
```

You can call this code on click of a button or you can call this page through cron job if ur using linux server or scheduler if ur using windows server